# Turn split screen input video into a single video cycling through each screen for 1 second?

Tags: ffmpeg

Given an input split screen video like this of 3840x2160 that is 29 minutes 2 seconds long
[image]

How do I convert it into the output format below?

- Basically I want to show each player for 1s and then jump to the next player and cycle throughout the video
- duration could be 1s, could be 2s, anything

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case, you would use the crop filter with expressions for shifting the crop region.

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf "crop=w=iw/2:h=ih/2:x='gte(mod(t\,2)\,1)*iw/2':y='gte(mod(t\,4)\,2)*ih/2'" -c:a copy out
```

This will move the crop window from top left --> top-right --> bottom-left --> bottom-right

Comment: well it switches every few frames but how do you switch it every second or 2s or 3s instead?

Comment: This switches view every second. For period of  X seconds, divide `t` by the period i.e. `mod(t\,2)` becomes `mod(t/X\,2)`

Comment: so basically t/x\,2 and t/X,4